# I have Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 version but in xampp php folder I have older version's extension

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have installed an older version of Oracle but in xampp PHP folder I have extension oci8_12 that is why I am having error when I try to connect to DB is there any way to use this function.

And also database is created with older version 11 can I access database with newer version.

```
<?php  
$DB = '//http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex';
$DB_USER = 'SYSTEM';
$DB_PASS = 'root';
$DB_CHAR = 'AL32UTF8';
echo 'Hello World';
$conn = oci_connect($DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB);
?>
```

```
Hello World
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shani\shobi.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if the extension is loaded. You need a special version for every PHP Version. Otherwise you can't load the extension. So first check your extension version.

But i think your version is not correct and your extension is not loaded.

On Windows you need a TS-Version (Thread safe) otherwise its not working.